# vscode showing "completion" for previous commands in integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using vscode v1.74.2.

[image: terminal showing completion]

When I updated vscode about one month ago, this "completion" of commands which i have previous run. I have searched though the settings, however I can't find the name of the feature. What is this featured named or how do I get rid of it?

Comment: What is the name of the terminal in vs code that you're using?

Answer (score 0):

I tried using pwsh in an external terminal and the "completion" appeared here too. This has nothing to do with vscode . Thanks [@perplexyves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20576394) for noting.

Edit: use right arrow for auto completion.